# php form issue, arrays & $_POST

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm currently trying to build a html/php form that allows the user to send their contact info and select quantity of pre-defined products. So far the contact info is working perfectly, it sends an email to my email containing the contact info BUT the quantity of each product does not work. Please help.

**Form Structure**

**Name:**
[INPUT FIELD]

**Lastname:**
[INPUT FIELD]

**Message:**
[INPUT FIELD]

**Products:**

Prod 1 [QUANTITY FIELD] - simple numeric input field

Prod 2 [QUANTITY FIELD] - simple numeric input field

Prod 3 [QUANTITY FIELD] - simple numeric input field

Anyways, here is the PHP code for my products, I'm using arrays.

```
<?php
    $my_products = array(
        '0' => 'product 0',
        '1' => 'product 1',
        '2' => 'product 2',
        '3' => 'product 3',
        '4' => 'product 4',
        '5' => 'product 5',
        '6' => 'product 6',
        '7' => 'product 7',
        '8' => 'product 8',
        '9' => 'product 9'
        '10' => 'product 10'
    );

    foreach ($my_products as $key => $value) {
        echo "<div class=\"col-xs-6\" style=\"margin: 10px 0 5px 0;\">";
            echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\" data-style=\"button\">";
                echo $value;
                echo "<input class=\"form-control selectBox\" maxlength=\"2\" min=\"0\" max=\"10\" type=\"number\" onkeypress=\"return isNumeric(event)\" oninput=\"maxLengthCheck(this)\" name=\"quantity[$key]>\"";
            echo "</li>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

I'm trying to echo out the result from the input field (quantity) but it doesn't work, it says that it's undefined.

Further down the html file I have the php mailing function and as I said everything works except the quantity.

```
 $products = array(
    @$_POST['quantity[0]'], 
    @$_POST['quantity[1]'], 
    @$_POST['quantity[2]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[3]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[4]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[5]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[6]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[7]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[8]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[9]'],
    @$_POST['quantity[10]']);

$message = "<br /><strong>".$products[0]." - product 0</strong>"
  . "<br /><strong>".$products[1]." - product 1</strong>"
  . "<br /><strong>".$products[2]." - product 2</strong>"
```

and so on..

Comment: `$products = $_POST['quantity'];`

Answer (score 3):

First of all don't use `@` sign. It's evil, really.

Your values are in `$_POST['quantity']` array so you can access it like that `$_POST['quantity'][2]`.

Comment: Updated the $products variable to:
$products = $_POST['quantity'];

And update the message echo to:
"<br /><strong>Product 3 - ".$_POST['quantity'][3]."</strong>"

Still doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesJ. learn how to debug. Use `var_dump` on `$_POST` and your array.

Comment: array(0) { } is what's coming up when I var_dump

Uninitialized string offset is also a notice I get for the quantity index

Comment: @JamesJ. maybe that's stupid question but did you send form via POST? I can't see that in your example.

Comment: Look man, the form works. It sends me an email including all the inputs in the form but the damn quantity is EMPTY. I don't know why!?!?

Comment: @JamesJ. you just said that `var_dump($_POST)` returns empty array so no, your form is not working. Or you are talking about another form.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The text was behind an element; this is what I got: 



array(6) { ["do"]=> string(7) "contact" ["ct_f_name"]=> string(24) "Babucar Matarr Diliwalay" ["ct_f_email"]=> string(32) "matarr.babucar@hotmailgambia.com" ["ct_f_tel"]=> string(11) "02124145454" ["quantity"]=> string(0) "" ["ct_message"]=> string(23) "dssssssssssssssssssssss" }

Comment: @JamesJ. you've got typo there. `name=\"quantity[$key]>\"` instead of `name=\"quantity[$key]\" />`.

Comment: You got me happy there for a minute. Fixed it, but still in the email no quantity is listed :(

Comment: @JamesJ. check var_dump again. Now there should be an array.

Comment: This is what I get after posting the form. array(6) { ["do"]=> string(7) "contact" ["ct_f_name"]=> string(10) "James Bond" ["ct_f_email"]=> string(24) "james.bond@hotmail.co.uk" ["ct_f_tel"]=> string(13) "0044734837483" ["quantity"]=> string(0) "" ["ct_message"]=> string(31) "Test message for StackOverflow." }

Comment: @JamesJ. strange, in your example everything looks ok. Can you show full script?

Comment: Yes. Should've just done it from the start lol. Here, I added it to Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/TBaBigm2

Answer (score 0):

The following example was tested and works (best practices have been "forgotten" just to keep things identical)
If you still have a problem with your code I suggest you to post the concerned files...

index.php

```
<?php
$my_products = array(
    '0' => 'product 0',
    '1' => 'product 1',
    '2' => 'product 2',
    '3' => 'product 3',
    '4' => 'product 4',
    '5' => 'product 5',
    '6' => 'product 6',
    '7' => 'product 7',
    '8' => 'product 8',
    '9' => 'product 9',
    '10' => 'product 10');

?>

<form action="show.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<?php
foreach ($my_products as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div class=\"col-xs-6\" style=\"margin: 10px 0 5px 0;\">";
        echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\" data-style=\"button\">";
            echo $value;
            echo "<input class=\"form-control selectBox\" maxlength=\"2\" min=\"0\" max=\"10\" type=\"number\" name=\"quantity[$key]>\"";
        echo "</li>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

show.php

```
<?php

$products = array(
$_POST['quantity']['0'],
$_POST['quantity']['1'],
$_POST['quantity']['2'],
$_POST['quantity']['3'],
$_POST['quantity']['4'],
$_POST['quantity']['5'],
$_POST['quantity']['6'],
$_POST['quantity']['7'],
$_POST['quantity']['8'],
$_POST['quantity']['9'],
$_POST['quantity']['10']);

$message = "<br /><strong>".$products[0]." - product 0</strong>"
  . "<br /><strong>".$products[1]." - product 1</strong>"
  . "<br /><strong>".$products[2]." - product 2</strong>";

echo $message;
?>
```